# How to fix incorrect barcode scanning?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, barcode, zxing

I use "me.dm7.barcodescanner: zxing: 1.9" to get the code from the barcode, the program works well but there is one problem. The program works even if the barcode is not in the rectangle and at this moment the program gives a completely different code unlike a barcode. How to make the program work when the barcode on the rectangle.

```
ViewGroup contentFrame = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ScanView);
mScannerView = new ZBarScannerView(this);

contentFrame.addView(mScannerView);

barcodeFormatEAN13 = BarcodeFormat.EAN13;
listaZaFormat.add(barcodeFormatEAN13);
mScannerView.setFormats(listaZaFormat);

askForPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, CAMERA);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the view finder the same size as the camera view because the entire camera view will be looking for a barcode.  Having used a zscanner with the software i work on it picks up stray barcodes sometimes.  if you make the frame smaller then it might be more controllable.